# XML Formatting issues using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, format, spacing

I am having trouble formatting my XML using an XSLT. At the moment I have the code written:

```
            <FileData>
                <File
                 FileNumber="{$ISCI}"
                 title="Test Ad"
                 advertiser="{$Advertiser}"
                />
            </FileData>
```

This in return give me an output formatted as so:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FileData>
      <File FileNumber="CBIPI3316B6" advertiser="SOKOLOVE LAW" title="Test Ad"/>
    </FileData>
```

I instead require a format:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FileData>
      <File 
       FileNumber=   "CBIPI3316B6" 
       advertiser=  "SOKOLOVE LAW" 
       title=            "Test Ad"
      />
```

Is there a simple way to convert this? I have tried using &#xa however I was unable to successfully change the output.

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing the lexical result in your XSLT code, instead you are writing instructions to create a result tree which can then be serialized. So whether you have a literal result element written as

```
<foo att1="value1" att2="value2"/>
```

or

```
<foo att1="value1"
     att2="value2"/>
```

does not determine how the serialized result of your XSLT code looks as far as the attributes are concerned. And the XSLT specifications, as far as I remember, make no prescriptions on attribute formatting and indentation. However the commercial editions of Saxon 9 support a serialization extension attribute `saxon:line-length` used to specify the line length on serialization, if you set that very low then each attribute ends up on a line of its own, so

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="ISCI" select="'foo'"/>
    <xsl:param name="Advertiser" select="'bar'"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" saxon:line-length="5"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <FileData>
            <File FileNumber="{$ISCI}" title="Test Ad" advertiser="{$Advertiser}"/>
        </FileData>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:transform>
```

for instance outputs

```
<FileData>
   <File FileNumber="foo"
         title="Test Ad"
         advertiser="bar"/>
</FileData>
```

You will have to check whether your XSLT processor provides something similar but in general if you really want a particular serialization then I think you need to write your own serializer to take the tree result of the XSLT transformation and serialize it or to plug into the XSLT processing tool chain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am not able to use saxon as part of my XSLT

Comment: @user6391187, I am not aware of any other XSLT processor providing some extension attributes to change the formatting. Anyway, the answer contains some hints like writing your own serializer that give an indication of what needs to be done. How that is done depends entirely on the used XSLT processor and its API and the used platform. So if you want concrete help then you would need to indicate which XSLT processor you use and how you use it as obviously writing and plugging in a custom serializer depends on some programming done outside of XSLT.